# Uncheck my checkbox based on other column value

Tags: angular, typescript, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I want to uncheck my checkbox automatically whenever a specific value (suppose 'x') is selected on my select box. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

The code for my selectbox is given below:

```
 <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'namesTemplate'">
            <dx-select-box  [searchEnabled]="true" [showClearButton]="true" [value]="data.value"
                            [dataSource]="names"
                            (onValueChanged)="setNames($event, data)">
            </dx-select-box>
</div>
```

Code for checkbox:

```
<dxi-column dataField="isChannel" editCellTemplate="cellTemplate"  cellTemplate="multiCellTemplate">
        <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'cellTemplate'">
            <dx-check-box [(value)]="data.value" (onValueChanged)="getValue($event, data)" [disabled]="isDisabled"></dx-check-box>
        </div>
        <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'multiCellTemplate'">
            <dx-check-box
                [(value)]="data.value" readOnly="true">
            </dx-check-box>
        </div>
 </dxi-column>
```

whenever `selectbox` value changes `onValueChanged` gets called, so I tried to change the value in that function but it didn't work.

```
 public setNames(obj: any, rowData: any): void {

        if (obj.value === 'x') {
            rowData.data.isChannel = false;
        }

  }
```

Comment: Show that not working code snippet, that you tried to change the value in the function.

Comment: provided, you can check!

Comment: Since you use a bidirectionnal binding for [(value)], changing "data.value" should be enough for updating the checkbox.

Comment: I want to uncheck my checkbox(if it's checked) whenever 'x' is selected in the select-box